# responsive columns with flexbox

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to get these columns to stack in this flexbox layout, here is my code.

```
<div class="team-row">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="team-member">               
            <img src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="Tommy Shrader" class="member-pic">
            <h3 class="member-title">Tommy Shrader</h3>
            <div class="member-position">
                <p>President and CEO</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">               
            <img src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="Zachery Reed" class="member-pic">
            <h3 class="member-title">Zachery Reed</h3>
            <div class="member-position">
                <p>Vice President of Operations</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">               
            <img src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="Mickie Breeding" class="member-pic">
            <h3 class="member-title">Mickie Breeding</h3>
            <div class="member-position">
                <p>Office Administration</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.team-row {
    width: 100%;
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #f7f7f8;
    }
    .wrap {
        padding: 80px 0 40px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        @media (max-width: 667px) {
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
    }
    .team-member {
        width: 27.06%;
        color: #444;
        text-align: center;
        .member-pic {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .member-title {
            font-family: 'Abolition Regular';
            font-size: 24pt;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .member-position {
            p {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 15pt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also setup a jsbin so you can see what I'm already trying to do.

https://jsbin.com/leyiqojuxa/edit?html,css,output

I'm trying to get the three items to stack on top of each other and center in the wrapper like normal when the screen gets to a certain width obviously.

I'm still a little new to flexbox layouts so I'm having trouble searching and understanding how to make this happen.

Comment: Looks like they stack fine to me...what exactly **isn't** working?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I want them to also center. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the columns already stack but you indicated that you wanted them to center.

Then you need to use `align-items`

```
    @media (max-width: 667px) {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
```

[**JSBin Demo**](https://jsbin.com/jebuhokuvu/1/edit?html,css,output)

[**CSS-Tricks - Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)